# SweetAlert while navigating to other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my application if I didnot click save and want to navigate from current page it should ask sweet alert `are you sure want to leave?` and two buttons `save and leave`. How can I do that.

Currently I am using jquery and It shows sweetalert box when I click on any anchor tag but immediately navigates to other page.

My Code is

```
jQuery(document).click(function(e) {
                if (jQuery(e.target).is('a')) {
                    swal({
                        title: "Are you sure?",
                        text: "Want to continue without saving?",
                        type: "warning",
                        showCancelButton: true,
                        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                        confirmButtonText: "Leave",
                        closeOnConfirm: false,
                        html: false
                        }

                    );
                }    
        });
```

Comment: Have a look at `preventDefault()` ...

Comment: did you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to prevent default behavior of an `<a>` element since you missed it, it will still redirect regarding of your action, second is that you need to redirect user if confirm was clicked in `swal` like:

```
jQuery(document).click(function(e)
{
  if (jQuery(e.target).is('a'))
  {
    // Prevent default behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    swal({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "Want to continue without saving?",
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
      confirmButtonText: "Leave",
      closeOnConfirm: false,
      html: false
    }, function (isConfirm) {

      if (isConfirm)
      {
        // If user clicked confirm navigate away
        window.location = jQuery(e.target).attr("href");
      }
    });

    return false;
  }
});
```

hope that helps

Comment: I tried this..but it triggers sweet alert when the page loads first time

Comment: I actually checked it in fiddle your issue does not persist, is there any declarations similar to this somewhere in your code?

Comment: No..This is the only place.But I did not put it in any function.is that required?

Comment: Try to wrap it with `jQuery.ready(function () {  //stuff } );` if it still persists

Comment: It is working correctly ,. only problem is when that page loads also it triggers the sweetalert. I dont want that. Afte page loads it is working correctly.

Comment: I could not guess anymore unless I see your actual code `I mean the original working copy of yours` there might be something that triggers the click event that aren't related to this problem anymore

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Event.preventDefault() or e.preventDefault()

That anchor tag `a` will create an event to navigate to its url, even if it's `href=#`.